# PostgreSQL negative "-0.0" in jsonb[] field

Tags: postgresql

I have an "issue" (probably coming from my understanding of the json, jsonb and jsonb[] types) which is the following:

My team and I insert 3D coordinates records into a table whose column type is `jsonb[]`.

The table contains an id column, that is based on the text representation of the records.
With that said, when I select some data from the table, all the records containing coordinates whose values where equal to -0.0 (bit sign on), the data I get back does not contain the minus sign. -0.0 -> 0.0.

I am aware of the IEEE754 RFC on floating point numbers (and the comparison section), I was wondering, how does Postgres treat the elements inside the jsonb array?
Is there a conversion/casting done on the fly when inserting the data.
Is there a way to deactivate such behaviour?

Minimal reproducible code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "my_test_table" (
    coordinates jsonb[]
);

TRUNCATE TABLE "my_test_table";


INSERT INTO 
    "public"."my_test_table" ("coordinates")
VALUES (
ARRAY[jsonb_build_array(-0.0, 0.0,0.0)]::jsonb[]
);


select * from my_test_table;
```

The output is:

```
{"[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"}
```

when one expects:

```
{"[-0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but [JSON specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8259/) (section "6. Numbers") allows implementations "to set limits on the range
and precision of numbers accepted". PostgreSQL actually parses JSON input and it doesn't seem to accept negative zero for regular numeric columns, so I presume it's using the same IEEE implementation here and not rolling one exclusively for JSON.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, that's what I'm asking...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález *"PostgreSQL actually parses JSON input and it doesn't seem to accept negative zero"* - [`json` does accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77524703/5298879), it's only only `jsonb` that doesn't, losing the sign when saving this as a numeric under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL stores numbers as `numeric` in `jsonb`. See this code in `src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c`:

```c
static JsonParseErrorType
jsonb_in_scalar(void *pstate, char *token, JsonTokenType tokentype)
{
    [...]

    switch (tokentype)
    {
        [...]
        case JSON_TOKEN_NUMBER:

            /*
             * No need to check size of numeric values, because maximum
             * numeric size is well below the JsonbValue restriction
             */
            Assert(token != NULL);
            v.type = jbvNumeric;
            if (!DirectInputFunctionCallSafe(numeric_in, token,
                                             InvalidOid, -1,
                                             _state->escontext,
                                             &numd))
                return JSON_SEM_ACTION_FAILED;
            v.val.numeric = DatumGetNumeric(numd);
            break;
        [...]
```

Data type `numeric` has no notion of “negative zero”:

```
SELECT -0::float8 AS float8, -0::numeric AS numeric;

 float8 │ numeric 
════════╪═════════
     -0 │       0
(1 row)
```

`numeric` is stored as binary coded decimal.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the other question:

> Is there a way to deactivate such behaviour?

Yes, there is. At a price of [everything `jsonb` offers over `json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSON): [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W-4g9xQb)

```
select a::json "json",
       a::jsonb "jsonb" 
from (values ('[-0.0,0.0,0.0]'))_(a);
```

| json | jsonb |
| --- | --- |
| [-0.0,0.0,0.0] | [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] |

```
create table test as 
select a::json "json",
       a::jsonb "jsonb" 
from (values ('[-0.0,1.1,2.2]'))_(a);

select 'json',
       json->>0 "->>",
       json->0 "->",
       pg_typeof(json->0),
       json->0 is json scalar AS "is json scalar",
       json_typeof(json->0)
from test
union all
select 'jsonb',
       jsonb->>0,
       (jsonb->0)::json,
       pg_typeof(jsonb->0),
       jsonb->0 is json scalar,
       jsonb_typeof(jsonb->0)
from test;
```

| ?column? | ->> | -> | pg_typeof | is json scalar | json_typeof |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| json | -0.0 | -0.0 | json | t | number |
| jsonb | 0.0 | 0.0 | jsonb | t | number |

If you need the `jsonb` functionality and the fields to be of `number` type while holding onto the bit sign for some other logic, you can save it under a separate, appropriately named key, or another array of `boolean` values that hold corresponding "source" bit signs of your coordinates: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/VylDPZri)

```
TRUNCATE TABLE "my_test_table";
alter table "public"."my_test_table" add column "source_bit_signs" jsonb[];

INSERT INTO "public"."my_test_table" ("coordinates","source_bit_signs")
select ARRAY[jsonb_build_array(x::numeric,y::numeric,z::numeric)]::jsonb[],
       ARRAY[jsonb_build_array(x~'-.*',y~'-.*',z~'-.*')]::jsonb[]
from (values ('-0.0', '0.0','0.0'))_(x,y,z)
returning *;
```

| coordinates | source_bit_signs |
| --- | --- |
| {"[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"} | {"[true, false, false]"} |

That of course forces you to bind those coordinates as string types instead of numeric types.

You can also *not* use `number`-type fields, and save the coordinates as `string` fields in `jsonb`. The size, indexing and JSONPath processing won't be the same, but other than that, most in-db type mapping on `json`/`jsonb` output goes through `text` type first anyways, before you get to interact with the field for the purpose of a query.